# Rails 3.1.3 -> 3.2.1 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My app has been running fine under 3.1.x for some time now. It currently is running under 3.1.3. I attempted to migrate to 3.2.1; however I get the following error every time I make a db query:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `synchronize' for nil:NilClass
```

This occurs with any active-record query such as User.first, User.all, User.find(1), etc. I have tried using multiple versions of the sqlite3 gem in development to see if that was the issue but I haven't had any luck. The version I tried was 1.3.5 w/ Rails 3.2.1.

Comment: I have the same problem... Here is the full stack trace (https://gist.github.com/1703964)

Comment: Mine was 1.9.3-p0. I can get a stack trace tonight, forgot to yesterday. If memory serves it had a fairly immediate hang in up active-record.rc2. I'll post for sure tonight though.

Comment: stack trace for me.. [https://gist.github.com/1707637](https://gist.github.com/1707637)

Comment: I backed off to rails 3.2.0 and the migration went fine. Looks to be a 3.2.1 issue for the moment.

Answer (score 4):

try update gem "kaminari" from "0.12.4" to "0.13.0"

Comment: It looks like a patch was added to rails to stop plugins from breaking this in the future. More info here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4757